How to Hot Reload XAML Hot Reload files in VS2022
While coding some Autodesk Revit addins using also WPF, I recently noticed that during debugging I get this:

It was working fine with my first addins but lately I cannot Hot Reload XAML files. Using VS2022 version 17.9.6.
I followed the instructions below - but still problem exists:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/tools-utilities/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2019
Is there anything else that might cause this issue?
Thank you!

There are some limitations mentioned in the documentation you posted. Verify that your XAML file has no errors. If your XAML file shows errors in the Error List, then XAML Hot Reload may not work. And have you tried a new project to check if hot reloading works?
